# Submit form details to another site via URL

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a little "track your parcel" widget on my site. It takes a simple code, or tracking number.

I wish to pass this to another site, where the tracking number is placed in the URL. For example:

```
http://www.site.co.uk/en/express/tracking.html?AWB=1234&brand=site
```

I wish to get the value placed in the form field, and build the URL using this code (where the 1234 is in the example above).

I have created a form, and a function which should get the value from the field. it should then open a new window going to this URL.

**Form HTML**:

```
<h2>Track your parcel</h2>
<form action="trackParcel()" method="GET">
    <input type="text" class="tracking" name="tracking" placeholder="Enter your waybill number" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Function**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        function trackParcel(){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('here');
            var tracking = $('.tracking').find('input[name="tracking"]').val();
            var url = 'http://www.site.co.uk/en/express/tracking.html?AWB='+tracking+'&brand=site';
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }  
    });
```

I had thought this would work correctly. That the function `trackParcel()` would be called when the form was submitted, that the `preventDefault()` would stop the form actually being submitted and that the `window.open` would open a new window with the URL I have created.

Am I way off here?

At present, it continues to submit the page (and therefore refreshes) and does not open a new window.

Comment: have you double checked the URI? Try with a static value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

Just do it directly in the HTML:

```
<h2>Track your parcel</h2>
<form action="http://www.site.co.uk/en/express/tracking.html" method="GET" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" class="tracking" name="AWB" placeholder="Enter your waybill number" />
    <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="site" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Changes:

- Make the action the URL of the other site's tracking page
- Add `target="_blank"` so it opens in a new window
- Change the form field name to `AWB` so it matches what the other site expects
- Add a hidden field for `brand=site`

Since the method is `GET`, the fields will be put on the URL as query parameters.

---

**Solution 2**:

`action="trackParcel()"` will try to open `trackParcel()` as a URL. If you want to call `trackParcel` on form submit, hook the `submit` event of the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("selector for the form").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('here');
        var tracking = $('.tracking').find('input[name="tracking"]').val();
        var url = 'http://www.site.co.uk/en/express/tracking.html?AWB='+encodeURIComponent(tracking)+'&brand=site';
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
});
```

Note the addition of `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Thanks, your HTML worked a charm. Classic me overthinking it!